# Folium (Maps with different data sources)

Tags: python, pandas, maps

I am starting to use Folium to generate interactive maps, of which I need to generate a map with markers from different data sources, that is, I have this:

```
#Data Sources

data1 = pd.read_excel('./data/Relevancia.xls')
data2 = pd.read_excel('./data/Zona.xls')
```

Data1 (Relevance) has the following structure (There are more than 500 data):

```
   lat         lon         event

--------------------------------------
-99.1483     19.2419      Bad
-99.2411     19.0561      Good
-99.5083     18.3361      Good
-99.2078     19.7153      Good
-99.9289     20.2961      Bad
```

Data2 (Zone) has the following structure (There are 100 data):

```
   x          y         locate

--------------------------------------
-99.1483     19.2419      CDMX
-99.2411     19.0561      Jalisco
-99.5083     18.3361      Edo Mexico
-99.2078     19.7153      Jalisco
-99.9289     20.2961      CDMX
```

What I require is to generate a map containing the two data sources. I have done this but with no expected results:

```
#Map
center = [20.5223, -99.8883]
map = folium.Map(location=center, zoom_start=8)
#Show Map
map
```

I generate the markers for data1:

```
Latitudes = data1['lat'].to_list()
Longitudes = data1['lon'].to_list()
Popups = data1['event'].to_list()

marker1 = []
for lat, long, pop in list(zip(Latitudes, Longitudes, Popups)):
    fLat = float(lat)
    fLon = float(long)
    if pop == "Malo":
        folium.Marker(
        location=[fLat,fLon],
        popup= pop,
        icon = folium.Icon(color = 'red', icon="remove-sign"))
    elif pop == "Bueno":
        folium.Marker(
        location=[fLat,fLon],
        popup= pop,
        icon = folium.Icon(color = 'green', icon="ok-sign"))

marker1.append([lat, long, pop])
```

I generate the markers for data2:

```
Latitudes1 = data2['x'].to_list()
Longitudes1 = data2['y'].to_list()
Popups1 = data2['locate'].to_list()

marker2 = []

for lat1, long1, pop1 in zip(Latitudes1, Longitudes1, Popups1):
    fLat1 = float(lat1)
    fLon1 = float(long1)
    folium.Marker(
        location=[fLat1,fLon1],
        popup= pop1,
        icon = folium.Icon(color = 'red', icon='home'))

marker2.append([lat1, long1, pop1])
```

I proceed to add attributes and markers to the map:

```
# Creamos dos grupos para los marcadores
feat1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Event')
feat2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Zone')

map.add_child(feat1)
map.add_child(feat2)

# I add the markers to the group they belong to, not to the map

marker1.add_to(feat1)
marker2.add_to(feat2)

# Now if I add the groups to the map

feat1.add_to(map)
feat2.add_to(map)

# In addition, layer control is added

folium.LayerControl().add_to(map)

#Show Map
map
```

The result is error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-48f67a4d9c56> in <module>
      7 
      8 # I add the markers to the group they belong to, not to the map
----> 9 marker1.add_to(feat1)
     10 marker2.add_to(feat2)
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add_to'

Pass the markers to a list but maybe I am not understanding the concept well, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could already solve. It was for issues of updating or reloading the map, where by rerunning the code, you can now see the markers separated by layers.